# Two different tables date columns should be same, amount column should be different, how to calculate monthly expenditure amount?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT month(date), SUM(amount) as amount
FROM expendituretotal
GROUP BY month(date);
```

I want output like this:

```
month    amount1   amount2
---------------------------
June       2000      3000
```

Comment: What should be amount1 and amount2 ?

Comment: amount1 column name in first table and amount2 column name in second table..date column is same in first and second table how to calculate month wise expenditure using two table....

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer.

```
SELECT e.month
    ,e.expp AS amount
    ,e1.depp AS amount
FROM (
     SELECT month(DATE) AS month
           ,SUM(amount) AS expp
     FROM expendituretotal
     GROUP BY month(DATE)
     ) e
    ,(
    SELECT month(DATE) AS month
          ,SUM(amount) AS depp
    FROM totalamount
    GROUP BY month(DATE)
    ) e1
WHERE e.month = e1.month
```

Comment: WITH expendituretotal as (
SELECT month(date) as month, SUM(amount) as expp
FROM expendituretotal
GROUP BY month(date)
),

totalamount as (
SELECT month(date) as month, SUM(amount) as depp
FROM totalamount
GROUP BY month(date)
)

select e.month, e.expp as amount, e1.depp as amount
from expendituretotal e
join totalamount e2 on e.month = e1.month

Comment: Change totalamount e2 to totalamount e1 There was a typo in my answer - it is corrected now.

Comment: WITH expendituretotal as (
SELECT month(date) as month, SUM(amount) as expp
FROM expendituretotal 
GROUP BY month(date)
),

totalamount as (
SELECT month(date) as month, SUM(amount) as depp
FROM totalamount 
GROUP BY month(date)
)

select e.month, e.expp as amount, e1.depp as amount
from expendituretotal e
join totalamount e1 on e.month = e1.month

Comment: write syntax near expendituretotal as  
 'expendituretotal as (
SELECT month(date) as month, SUM(amount) as expp
FROM ex at' line 1

Comment: Corrected again as mysql does not support CTE's :( This must work.

Comment: Please acccept the answer if the code worked, thanks :)